# How to get MAX date from table join that use UNION?

Tags: mysql, join, union-all

I have 3 table that need to be joined to get the max date.

```
table_grade_A
ID_GRADE    GRADE      NOTE    SURVEYOR
       1     70.7      PASS         TOM
       3     51.2      FAIL         TOM

table_grade_B
ID_GRADE    SUB_GRADE_I   SUB_GRADE_II   TOTAL_GRADE     NOTE    SURVEYOR
       2           30.8           40.1          70.9     PASS     MARVOLO
       4           10.3           54.1          64.4     FAIL     MARVOLO                       
       5           41.7           20.9          62.6     FAIL      RIDDLE 

table_grade
ID_GRADE    STUDENT       TEST_DATE
       1       MIYA      2018-12-20   
       2      LAYLA      2018-12-21
       3       MIYA      2018-12-21
       4       MIYA      2018-12-22
       5     KARRIE      2018-12-28
```

Every student may get different test and different test stored in different table. I use `UNION` to populate the value from `table_grade_a` and `table_grade_b` and JOIN them to `table_grade`

My current query:

```
SELECT tg.STUDENT, MAX(tg.TEST_DATE) AS 'TEST_DATE', temp_grade.* FROM `table_grade` tg 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ID_GRADE,GRADE,NOTE
   FROM table_grade_a 'tga'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT ID_GRADE,TOTAL_GRADE AS GRADE,NOTE 
   FROM table_grade_a 'tgb'
)temp_grade ON tg.ID_GRADE = temp_grade.ID_GRADE 

WHERE tg.STUDENT = 'MIYA'
```

The result of above query is:

```
STUDENT    TEST_DATE    GRADE    NOTE
  MIYA    2018-12-22     70.7    PASS
```

The expected output should be:

```
STUDENT    TEST_DATE    GRADE    NOTE
  MIYA    2018-12-22     64.4    FAIL
```

Answer (score 3):

For a result corresponding the the max date of each student:

The MIN or MAX of a column does not necessarily align to the other values of the wanted row(s), so you need to do more than just calculate the maximum date. In MySQL prior to version 8 you could do something like this, by calculating the maximum dates then using that as an inner join to limit the rows to those corresponding to the maximum values:

```
select
    temp_grade .*
from table_grade tg
inner join (
    select student, max(test_date) as test_date
    from table_grade
    group by student
    ) gd on tg.student = gd.student and tg.test_date = gd.test_date
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ID_GRADE,GRADE,NOTE
   FROM table_grade_a 'tga'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT ID_GRADE,TOTAL_GRADE AS GRADE,NOTE 
   FROM table_grade_a 'tgb'
   )temp_grade ON tg.ID_GRADE = temp_grade.ID_GRADE 
# WHERE tg.STUDENT = 'MIYA'
```

In MySQL v8+ you could use `row_number() over(...)` instead:

```
select
      temp_grade .*
from (
    select *
    , row_number() over(partition by student order by test_date DESC) as rn
    from table_grade
    )  tg
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ID_GRADE,GRADE,NOTE
   FROM table_grade_a 'tga'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT ID_GRADE,TOTAL_GRADE AS GRADE,NOTE 
   FROM table_grade_a 'tgb'
   )temp_grade ON tg.ID_GRADE = temp_grade.ID_GRADE 
where tg.rn = 1
# and tg.STUDENT = 'MIYA'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current approach is that you are selecting the max date, a table level aggregate, while also asking for all individual records at the same time.  This does make sense.  One correct possibility would be to use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT tg1.STUDENT, tg1.TEST_DATE, tg2.*
FROM table_grade tg1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID_GRADE, GRADE, NOTE
    FROM table_grade_a
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID_GRADE, TOTAL_GRADE, NOTE 
    FROM table_grade_b
) tg2
    ON tg1.ID_GRADE = tg2.ID_GRADE 
WHERE
    tg1.STUDENT = 'MIYA'
ORDER BY
    tg1.TEST_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```